# Is it possible to convert zxing qrcode byteMatrix to bytearray without using the bufferedImage class?

Tags: java, html, servlets, arrays, zxing

I need to convert the byteMatrix data that I get from zxing's qrcode function to byte[], and then send this data in servlet to html page for image displaying.

And I am running this app in java1.3, which bufferedImage class is not supported.

I searched the web for almost 4~5 days, still couldn't find anything.

So I am wondering is it possible to implement this without using the bufferedImage?

Thank you very much for your help.

Amy

Comment: What is the reason for the 1.3 requirement?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't tell you the reason, I am in pain with this restriction T_T~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you want to use `BufferedImage`? It's certainly available in a Java 1.3 environment.

What do you mean by `byte[]` -- bytes representing an *image*, in some format? Use `ImageIO` to write the `BufferedImage` to a stream like your servlet output stream after setting the response content type.

Comment: Because the running environment doesn't support bufferedImage. I tried to use bufferedImage and it doesn't work (says that "class not found" when running the apps). and for the byte[], I mean image in image/jpeg format.

Comment: It's not possible to have a servlet environment without Java SE classes like BufferedImage; you're doing something wrong. If it's really not available, you have to write your own code to create a JPEG or PNG image data from the byte matrix. The project uses ImageIO to do this, and that uses BufferedImage.

Comment: Yea you may be right, I will double check the problem again. And thank you so much for your help and advise. Now I know the bufferedImage is needed for servlet. By the way, is it true that each value of the byteMatrix represent a pixel?

Comment: `BufferedImage` is not needed by an `HttpServlet`, but, servlets are part of JavaEE, which is a superset of JavaSE, which contains `BufferedImage`. It's in every Java program, excepting those based on subsets like Android or JavaME. Each value in `ByteMatrix` is a pixel, yes. true == black.